# Flutter Webview 4.0.2's WebViewCookieManager.setCoookie does not work for IOS apps

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cookies, flutterwebviewplugin

I have been working with flutter_webview 3 and just recently upgraded to flutter_webview 4. It has a cookie authentication which used to work with the previous version of flutter webview.
I have migrated most of the things, but cookie authentication isn't going as expected.
I am not sure if this is a library issue or code one, so I do apologize in advance.
I have looked at the documentation and tried many things

Note:

1. authentication works with initialCookies of flutter_webview 3(both for ios and Android)
2. Initializing Cookies with WebViewCookieManager.setCoookie worked for Android
3. IOS authentication works when header is passed with url through loadRequest() of webviewcontroller. But it wotks only for the initial url that was passed through loadRequest. When a button is pressed on the page authentication fails an logs out

Code sample is given below. appreciate your help.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
import 'package:webview_cookie_manager/webview_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
// Import for Android features.
import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';
// Import for iOS features.
import 'package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.dart';


class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewPage> createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  late final WebViewController controller;
  late final WebViewCookieManager cookieManager;
  bool isLoading = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

        // platformwise Cookie implementation
    var cookieParams = const PlatformWebViewCookieManagerCreationParams();

    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      cookieParams = WebKitWebViewCookieManagerCreationParams
          .fromPlatformWebViewCookieManagerCreationParams(
        cookieParams,
      );
    } else if (WebViewPlatform.instance is AndroidWebViewPlatform) {
      cookieParams = AndroidWebViewCookieManagerCreationParams
          .fromPlatformWebViewCookieManagerCreationParams(
        cookieParams,
      );
    }

    cookieManager = WebViewCookieManager.fromPlatformCreationParams(
      cookieParams,
    );

  
        // platformwise controller implementation 
    var params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();

    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams
          .fromPlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        params,
      );
    } else if (WebViewPlatform.instance is AndroidWebViewPlatform) {
      params = AndroidWebViewControllerCreationParams
          .fromPlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        params,
      );
    }

    final initController = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params)
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
            });
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: onPageFinished,
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: onNavigationRequest,
        ),
      );

    controller = initController;

    getPreferenceData();

        
  }

Future<void> getPreferenceData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // COOKIE = {'ID': 123, 'TOKEN': 'abcd'}
    final cookieHashString = prefs.getString('COOKIE') ?? '';
    if (cookieHashString != '') {
      final cookieHash = json.decode(cookieHashString);

      headers = <String, String>{
        'Cookie':
            'TOKEN=${cookieHash["TOKEN"]};ID=${cookieHash["ID"]};'
      };

      await setWebViewCookie(headers, cookieHash);
    }
}

Future<void> setWebViewCookie(
    Map<String, String> headers,
        Map<String, String> cookieHash,

  ) async {
    // This is required for android
    // Doesn't work in IOS. Adding header works on IOS
    // But only for first load. when any button n webview is clicked suthentication fails 
        await cookieManager.setCookie(
      WebViewCookie(
        name: 'ID',
        value: cookieHash['ID'].toString,
        domain: _baseUrl,
      ),
    );

    await cookieManager.setCookie(
      WebViewCookie(
        name: 'TOKEN',
        value: cookieHash['TOKEN'].toString,
        domain: _baseUrl,
      ),
    );

    // SetHeader(without this IOS auth doesnt work)
    await controller.loadRequest(
      Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/member/'),
      headers: headers,
    );
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // detect Android back button click
        if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
          await controller.goBack();

          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              WebViewWidget(
                controller: controller,
              ),
              if (isLoading) const LoadingWidget() else Stack(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Did you find a workaround? Or have you opened an issue with the developers? We're using version 4.2.0 and seem to be running into the same problem.

Comment: I was in a hurry, so I changed to flutter_inappwebview. and it worked without any problem. Sorry couldn't be of much help.